# How can I generate debian weak-keys?

Tags: linux, openssl, debian

I need to generate debian weak-keys for non standard bits that are not included in the official black-lists by Linux (those are only fro: 512, 1024, 2048, 4096) . Can any body guide me to how can I achieve generate debian weak-keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you could write a program that generates these lists. But the easy way is probably to replicate the bug in a virtual environment. See [Debian OpenSSL Predictable PRNG Toys](http://digitaloffense.net/tools/debian-openssl/) for example.

Note that the generated weak keys are architecture dependant. That is different architecture will generate different weak keys. But they are *all* weak keys of course.